# How to prevent camel redeliver files from sftp in case of exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have following camel configuration:

```
from("file://" + FTP_FILES + "?idempotent=true")
.process(new Processor() {
     @Override
     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         throw new RuntimeException("test");             
     }
 }).onException(Exception.class).maximumRedeliveries(0);
```

This code works in infinite loop and tried to process same file.

Is it possible to configure camel just ignore exception?

### P.S.

I also tried

```
.onException(RuntimeException.class).continued(true);
```

and

```
.onException(RuntimeException.class).handled(true)
```

but result the same

### P.S.

I just want behaviour same as this code provide:

```
from("file://" + FTP_FILES + "?idempotent=true")
.process(new Processor() {
     @Override
     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         try{ 
             throw new RuntimeException("test");
         } catch(RuntimeException e){
             // just ignore  
         }             
     }
 })
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use

Comment: @Claus, fresh version - 2.20

Comment: @Claus Ibsen, to be exact I use CAMEL_VERSION = "2.20.0"

Answer (score 0):

See this unit test that demonstrates hos this is possible: https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/fcd200c4e13c35bb9a63924bbc3e2d6a643c31cf

The error handler will catch the exception and handle it, and the file consumer will regard the file as processed successfully, and move the file to the `.camel` sub folder (default behaviour).

Comment: Is it global setting for all routes declared inside configure method?

Comment: Yes, if you are learning Camel then consider picking up the CiA 2nd ed book, or any of the other books. You can learn a lot faster.